# Java Android Bluetooth Socket Unresolved Symbol

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth, bluetooth-socket

I am trying to setup a Bluetooth connection between an Android device and an rPi. However I am getting an unresolved symbol error on socket in the testouput function. However, socket works just fine further down the code. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Thanks!

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
  ListView listView;
  BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
  Set<BluetoothDevice> devicesArray;
  ArrayList<String> pairedDevices;
  ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> devices;
   public static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
  protected static final int SUCCESS_CONNECT = 0;
  protected static final int MESSAGE_READ = 1;
  IntentFilter filter;
  BroadcastReceiver receiver;
  String tag = "debugging";
  Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
     @Override
     public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(tag, "in handler");
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        switch(msg.what){
        case SUCCESS_CONNECT:
           // DO something
           ConnectedThread connectedThread = new ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket)msg.obj);
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CONNECT", 0).show();
           String s = "successfully connected";
           connectedThread.write(s.getBytes());
           Log.i(tag, "connected");
           break;
        case MESSAGE_READ:
           byte[] readBuf = (byte[])msg.obj;
           String string = new String(readBuf);
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string, 0).show();
           break;
        }
     }
  };
  @Override
  public void testoutput(String str){
     final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
     mmSocket = socket;
     byte[] toSend=str.getBytes();
     OutputStream mmOutStream = socket.getOutputStream();
     mmOutStream.write(toSend);
  }
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.bluetooth);
       init();
       if(btAdapter==null){
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No bluetooth detected", 0).show();
          finish();
       }
       else{
          if(!btAdapter.isEnabled()){
             turnOnBT();
          }

          getPairedDevices();
          startDiscovery();
       }


   }
  private void startDiscovery() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
     btAdapter.startDiscovery();

  }
  private void turnOnBT() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Intent intent =new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
     startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
  }
  private void getPairedDevices() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     devicesArray = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
     if(devicesArray.size()>0){
        for(BluetoothDevice device:devicesArray){
           pairedDevices.add(device.getName());

        }
     }
  }
  private void init() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
     listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
     listAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,0);
     listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
     btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
     pairedDevices = new ArrayList<String>();
     filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
     devices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
     receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           String action = intent.getAction();

           if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
              BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
              devices.add(device);
              String s = "";
              for(int a = 0; a < pairedDevices.size(); a++){
                 if(device.getName().equals(pairedDevices.get(a))){
                    //append 
                    s = "(Paired)";
                    break;
                 }
              }

              listAdapter.add(device.getName()+" "+s+" "+"\n"+device.getAddress());
           }

           else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)){
              // run some code
           }
           else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)){
              // run some code
           }
           else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)){
              if(btAdapter.getState() == btAdapter.STATE_OFF){
                 turnOnBT();
              }
           }

        }
     };

     registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
      filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
     registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
      filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
     registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
      filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
     registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
  }


  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onPause();
     unregisterReceiver(receiver);
  }

     @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth must be enabled to continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           finish();
        }
     }
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
           long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(btAdapter.isDiscovering()){
           btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
        if(listAdapter.getItem(arg2).contains("Paired")){

           BluetoothDevice selectedDevice = devices.get(arg2);
           ConnectThread connect = new ConnectThread(selectedDevice);
           connect.start();
           Log.i(tag, "in click listener");
        }
        else{
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "device is not paired", 0).show();
        }
     }

     private class ConnectThread extends Thread {

        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
         private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

         public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
             // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
             // because mmSocket is final
             BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
             mmDevice = device;
             Log.i(tag, "construct");
             // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
             try {
                 // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
                 tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
             } catch (IOException e) { 
                Log.i(tag, "get socket failed");

             }
             mmSocket = tmp;
         }

         public void run() {
             // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
             btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
             Log.i(tag, "connect - run");
             try {
                 // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
                 // until it succeeds or throws an exception
                 mmSocket.connect();
                 Log.i(tag, "connect - succeeded");
             } catch (IOException connectException) {   Log.i(tag, "connect failed");
                 // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
                 try {
                     mmSocket.close();
                 } catch (IOException closeException) { }
                 return;
             }

             // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)

             mHandler.obtainMessage(SUCCESS_CONNECT, mmSocket).sendToTarget();
         }



        /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
         public void cancel() {
             try {
                 mmSocket.close();
             } catch (IOException e) { }
         }
     }

     private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
         private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
         private final InputStream mmInStream;
         private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

         public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
             mmSocket = socket;
             InputStream tmpIn = null;
             OutputStream tmpOut = null;

             // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
             // member streams are final
             try {
                 tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                 tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
             } catch (IOException e) { }

             mmInStream = tmpIn;
             mmOutStream = tmpOut;
         }

         public void run() {
             byte[] buffer;  // buffer store for the stream
             int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

             // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
             while (true) {
                 try {
                     // Read from the InputStream
                    buffer = new byte[1024];
                     bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                     // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                     mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                             .sendToTarget();

                 } catch (IOException e) {
                     break;
                 }
             }
         }

         /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
         public void write(byte[] bytes) {
             try {
                 mmOutStream.write(bytes);
             } catch (IOException e) { }
         }

         /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
         public void cancel() {
             try {
                 mmSocket.close();
             } catch (IOException e) { }
         }
     }
```

Comment: Did you import `android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket`

Comment: It probably only works "farther down the code" because the compiler gave up after the first unresolved reference. What is `socket`? Where is it defined? What are you expecting `mmSocket` to be referencing in that method?

Comment: @Satya - Yes, import android.bluetooth.*

Comment: @CraigOtis - It works further down the code, because we implemented this incrementally. So before I added testoutput, the code worked. mmSocket is a Bluetooth socket. I thought it would be the output. ~shrug~

Comment: It only works further down the code (in the constructor for `ConnectedThread`) because there's a `BluetoothSocket socket` being provided as a constructor arg. But there's no reason to assume that this locally-scoped variable would be available at the global scope.

Comment: I see that they are declaring `private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;` Does it have to be `private`? Should I remove it from the function and make it a public declaration?